# Table Primary Key for MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, performance, key

Is it useful to add a primary key (Auto increment) to a table for better performance? This ID wouldn't be used in the queries, but maybe it's useful for the performance anyhow.

One of my tables has no primary key/unique/index and is working very slow.
So is it better to add such an ID or should I make 3 columns to one primary key (since they have to be together to be unique)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to have `PK`, aditional You can add `UNIQUE` index on other collumns to suppotr them

Comment: so its better to have one

Comment: wow, the UNIQUE helped SO much :D one of my queries took about 7 seconds approximately and now it's less than 0.1 second. I can't even believe it.

Comment: it's because when he finds one 'UNIQE' match, then he stops seaeching. `Limit 1` works the same.

Answer (score 1):

I like to always have an ID integer auto increment because you never know when you will need to reference this table from others or find an specific row based on an attribute ( findById(), for example. ID integer auto increment column is perfect for it lol )

Having that said, the problem of queries being slow depend on each query. Look at your WHERE clause. Do you search by those 3 columns that are unique together? Then add one index on top of those 3 columns (and make it unique, since they are unique together). If your queries search by one column only, add an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes only improve performance of queries that search the column being indexed. A primary key that isn't used will have no effect on performance.

If your queries are running slowly, make sure you have indexes on the columns that you're searching heavily (a column doesn't have to be unique to have an index). And use `EXPLAIN` to see how MySQL is optimizing the query, and whether it's making use of those indexes.

If you're having trouble with a particular query, start a new question where you post your database schema and the query in question, and we may be able to help you.